# Laravel format user's data sent to view

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing, laravel-8, laravel-controller

I want to return my user's data with a specific field formatted differently.

Users have a field `some_field` which contains a string, let's say `abcdef`. I want to format it like so : `ab cd ef` - which I can do using `wordwrap($user->some_field, 2, ' ', true);`

So I'm doing:

```
public function dashboard(Request $request) {
    $request->user()->some_field = wordwrap($request->user()->some_field, 2, ' ', true);

    return view('dashboard', [
        'user' => $request->user(),
    ]);
}
```

Is it possible to apply this somehow for each and every time a user's data is returned, or do I have to make it happen in every controller returning user's data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model you have to define accessor have a look here: [Defining An Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

In your case it will look like this:

```
public function getSomeFieldAttribute($value)
    {
        return wordwrap($value, 2, ' ', true);
    }
```